# Procedural/imperative programming - Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, procedural-programming

Can you please help me understand what ports in r if `x = 0,1,2,3`

```
y <-- 0
z <-- 1
r <-- z

while y < x {
Multiply z by 2;
Add z to r;
Increase y; }
```

Comment: Is this an actual programming language or pseudocode? Is this homework?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In every looping step z is multiplied by 2, so you have the values 2,4,8,16... (or generally 2^n).

r is initially 1, and if you add z, you get 3,7,15,31 (generally 2^(n+1) - 1)

For x = 0 the loop will be skipped, so r stays 1

For x = 1 the loop will... uhm... loop one time, so you get 3
etc.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the algorithm computes the sum of the powers of two from `0` to `x` and uses `r` as an accumulator for this. On termination, `r` holds the value `2^(x+1)-1`.